# Permission denied - readline() on closed filehandle

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, readline, zentyal

I'm having a problem when trying to import a user list into Zentyal 3.4.

The script I'm using is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use EBox;
use EBox::Users::User;

EBox::init();

my $usersMod = EBox::Global->getInstance()->modInstance('users');
my $parent = $usersMod->objectFromDN('ou=Promo 2022,ou=Alumnos,'.$usersMod->ldap->dn());

my $file = 'users.csv';
open (my $USERS, $file) or die "Can't open '$file': $!";

while (my $line = <$USERS>) {
    chomp ($line);
    my ($username, $givenname, $surname, $password) = split(';', $line);
    EBox::Users::User->create(
    uid => $username,
    parent => $parent,
    givenname => $givenname,
    surname => $surname,
    password => $password,
    );
}

close ($USERS);

1;
```

It worked perfectly the first time I used it but now it gives a "Permission denied" error when it tries to open the file.

Both the file intended to open and the script have `0777` permissions so any user should be able to do whatever the please with them.

The script needs to be run as sudo (which I did).

Comment: Is it saying `Can't open 'users.csv': Permission denied"`?

Comment: If the script is run with `sudo`, permissions should be ignored.

Comment: @Barmar I know permissions are ignored when running as sudo, just mentioned it to avoid people saying "You should run the script as sudo".

And yes, that is exactly the output I'm getting.

Comment: @JakeGould I know 0777 is horrible but I've tried everything with no success. If I don't have permissions to run perl, I shouldn't even be able to run the script, right? Besides, the script worked just fine the first time I used it, which was only yesterday.

Comment: @JakeGould 'users.csv' is readable. `head users.csv` gives me a few lines of the csv file. I've tried with the full path but got the same result.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you still getting this error if the script is run with `sudo`?

Comment: @Borodin yes, I still get the error when using `sudo`. Also, the script cannot be run without `sudo` because it won't be able to use EBox

Comment: Solved it. The problem was that although I could read the files, the folder `/home/angardi` was set to `0700`, so perl couldn't read the file.

Thanks to everyone for your help

Comment: @angardi: Please submit your solution as an answer and accept it so that others can see that your question has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solved it by the OP in the comments.*

The relevant files had permissions `0777`.  However, the containing folder `/home/angardi` was set to `0700`.

Therefore, although I could read the files, perl didn't have permissions to read.